# Pandas - find rows sharing two out the three common values, order-independent, and collect values pairs

Tags: pandas, numpy

Given a dataframe, I am looking for rows where two out of three values are in common, regardless of the columns, hence order, in which they appear. I would like to then collect those common pairs.
Please note

- a couple of values can appear at most in two rows
- a value can appear only once in a row

I would like to know what the most efficient/elegant way is in numpy or pandas to solve this problem.

For example, taking as input the dataframe

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2,5,1], 'col2': [1, 7,1,2],'col3': [3, 3,1,7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    col1    col2    col3
0   1   2   3
1   2   7   3
2   5   1   2
3   9   2   7
```

I expect as result an array, list, something as

```
1  2
2  3
2  7
```

as the values (1,2) , (2,3) and (2,7) are present in two rows (first and third, first and second, and second and forth respectively).

I cannot find a concise solution.
At the moment I skecthed a numpy solution such as

```
def func(x):
    rows, columns = x.shape[0], x.shape[1]
    res = []
    for i in range(0,rows):
        for j in range(i+1, rows):
            aux = np.intersect1d(x[i,:], x[j,:])
            if aux.size>1:
                res.append(aux)
    return res
```

which outputs

```
func(df.values)

Out: [array([2, 3]), array([1, 2]), array([2, 7])]
```

It looks well cumbersome, how could get it done with one of those cool numpy/pandas one-liners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using python built in set operations to do most of the heavy lifting, just apply them with pandas:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2,5,9], 'col2': [2, 7,1,2],'col3': [3, 3,2,7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

pairs = df.apply(set, axis=1).apply(lambda x: set(itertools.combinations(x, 2))).explode()
out = set(pairs[pairs.duplicated()])
```

Output:

```
{(2, 3), (1, 2), (2, 7)}
```

Optionally to get it in `list[np.ndarray]` format:

```
out = list(map(np.array, out))
```

Comment: thanks for this very instructive. Just one thing, I fear the procedure could fail if two tuples in pairs are like `(x,y)` and `(y,x)` as  `.duplicated()` will then not detect them up. I prevented  a `sorted` function to ensure tuples' element are in ascending order, eliminating the mentioned possibility. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Similar approach to that of @Chrysophylaxs but in pure python:

```
from itertools import combinations
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(s for x in df.to_numpy().tolist() for s in set(combinations(set(x), r=2)))

out = [k for k,v in c.items() if v>1]
# [(2, 3), (1, 2), (2, 7)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df=df.assign(col4=df.index)

def function1(ss:pd.Series):
    ss1=ss.value_counts().loc[lambda ss:ss>=2]
    return ss1.index.tolist() if ss1.size>=2 else None

df.merge(df,how='cross',suffixes=('','_2')).query("col4!=col4_2").filter(regex=r'col[^4]', axis=1)\
    .apply(function1,axis=1).dropna().drop_duplicates()
```

out

```
1    [2, 3]
2    [1, 2]
7    [2, 7]
```